# I enter a specific step in cucumber - a click on a button is simulated, without me triggering it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

I use selenium to detect 2 buttons in a webpage.

My test is using cucumber.

Unfortunately, when I enter a specific step in cucumber -

a click on a button is simulated, without me triggering it.

Is this a known issue?

**my steps:**

```
Feature: app inbox
  Scenario: app nav inbox
    Given There exists an admin logged in client
    And I navigate to offer "app_navigable" inbox page
    Then text should be as follows:
      | name         | visibility | text                               |
      | inbox_title1 | true       | Here’s the link to the app nav app |
      | inbox_title2 | true       | app nav mail title                 |
```

**in the first line of this method the button is clicked:**

```
@And("^text should be as follows:$")
public void text_should_be_as_follows(List<Map<String,
        String>> previewPropList) throws Throwable {
    Map<String, String> previewProps;
    for (int i = 0; i < previewPropList.size(); i++) {
```

any more data I can add to figure it out?

Comment: cucumber doesn't have anything to do with button click. Do you have any `Background` step? Is there any 'similar' step in any other step definition?  What happens in the step before?

Comment: I don't know what `Background step` is. How do a similar step look like? Nothing special happens in the previous step. no click btw

Comment: Is your code available to check? I'm 100% sure this has nothing to do with cucumber

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late answer but I ran into a similar issue yesterday and maybe it can be useful for someone.

Did you have a `.sendkeys()` method somewhere in your code, which takes input data from string list or an external source? Because if there's a `"\n" newline` or other escape sequence at the end of the input string, it will trigger an "enter" key press, this can be triggering the button (not actually a click).